# Assign label to Powerpoint Add-in Object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

Can I assign a label to a specific Powerpoint Add-in object (prefer written in C# language)? For example, is it possible to add a button in the corner of each shape of a slide? Please take a look at the following figure:

[image]

As I understand, there are 2 cases.

1) The label is a Powerpoint shape. By this way, the label can be confused with other shapes. So, I don't like this approach very much.

2) The label could be a Windows.Forms.Button ???

In both case, when moving a specific shape, I want the label is always moving with the shape as well. I don't know whether Powerpoint Add-in feature can allow us assign a label to its shape or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can create panels for this programmatically. Add a button and a label in that panel,set location where you want,set buttons events.

Comment: Yes, it's the final solution I think is using a panels storing labels. So, there's no way to add a float label that can be attached to a specific shape??

Comment: @chipbk10 labels only can have some text and font things inside it no image or other.So yes,There is no way I think.